# Extinction of the dwarves

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind, the-elder-scrolls-series

I was playing some of the elder scrolls games like Morrowind and Skyrim when I found out about the dwarves. I wanted to explore their ruins and kill many of their robots. Then I found out later why I couldn't find a single dwarf in morrowind or skyrim [Despite Yagrum Bagarn]. I  don't know what happened to the dwarves. Does anybody know theories or evidence about the extinction?

Comment: I actually doubt people from bethesda themselves know about the disappearance of the dwarves..!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of diferent ways, the dwemer could have disappeard.
I am going to sum up a few from the [Imperial Library](http://www.imperial-library.info/content/definitive-guide-dwemer). I assume, that you already know something about "[Kagrenac](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Kagrenac) and his [tools](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Kagrenac's_Tools)" else i really recomend to read the articles i linked.

1. > The tools worked. Kagrenac successfully used his tools, and possibly
   >   The Calling, to take his race and remove them from Mundus, the Mortal
   >   Plane. He either turned them into Deities or simply allowed them to
   >   move freely in the Outer Realms.
2. > The tools failed. Kagrenac foolishly de-created his race and erased
   >   them from Nirn. They were either destroyed entirely or were transfered
   >   to somewhere outside of Nirn and died.
3. > Kagrenac had no chance to actually use the tools. The split second
   >   that he did, Daedra Prince Azura snatched him and all of the other
   >   Dwemer from Nirn, and imprisoned them in Oblivion. Alternatively, he
   >   did use the tools, but as soon as his race was removed from Mundus,
   >   Azura imprisoned them in Oblivion. Or he died before he had the
   >   chance, and Azura instructed Nerevar to use the tools to destroy the
   >   Dwemer enchantment upon the Heart, making them instantly disappear.
   >   Either way, Azura put them in Oblivion and there they may or may not
   >   have died.

I already mentioned it but those are only speculations, of how it could have happened.

Sources: 
http://www.imperial-library.info/ 
http://www.uesp.net/